# Игровые сайты с сервером

Tags: веб-сервер

Как написать игровые сайты?

Если у тебя очень старый ноутбук - заходишь на сайт, выбираешь игру, а потом играешь без скачиваний online.

Как установить на сайт готовую игру, типа GTA 5, Call of Duty и тому подобные, чтобы без скачиваний играть.

Comment: Если кратко, то игры запускаются на виртуальной машине, а тебе при помощи AJAX транслируется то, что происходит в игре.

Comment: Как это сделать ну типа как сайт Playkey

Comment: Как я написал выше

Comment: Voprositel пожалуйста как занести готовую игру на html чтобы можно было поиграть online без скачиваний

Comment: никак, надеюсь тебя устроит. Только если арендовать виртуальную машину, на которой будет запускаться игра, тогда ты сможешь транслировать это на страничку. PlayKey и подобные сервисы именно так и работают.

Comment: Вам стоит изучить, как [создать минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
это очень важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем

Answer (score 2):

### Как работают такие сервисы

Вкратце - передаётся видеопоток клиенту с машины, на которой запущена сама игра. На страничке браузера используется что-то вроде видеоплеера, который отправляет нажатые клавиши на сервер с работающей игрой.

### Заниматься подобным вопросом, думаю, не стоит

Лет пять назад начали рекламировать PlayKey. Я уже тогда знал что это провальная идея и будет пользоваться спросом только теми, кто не может себе позволить дорогое железо. Интернет хоть и стал лучше, но всё равно всегда будут задержки, потери пакетов, плохой битрейт и т.д.

Такие сервисы даже в ближайшем будущем не смогут существовать. Что тем самым Google и NVidia продемонстрировали в недавнее время.

Даже в локальной сети с высокой скоростью я не готов смотреть на стриминговый видеопоток и предпочитаю смотреть на отрисовку графики своим железом на своём мониторе.

Comment: Вот так и рушатся мечты 

Comment: *"Что тем самым Google и NVidia продемонстрировали в недавнее время."* — что продемонстрировали? Можно ссылку? Последний абзац слишком субъективный

Comment: @dIm0n [гифка](https://twitter.com/i/status/1196488999524802562) из твиттера скажет больше, чем ссылки на статьи

Comment: От того же человека [гифка](https://twitter.com/GenePark/status/1196546198674518016), это мало что доказывает

Comment: @dIm0n Мой ответ субъективный. Поэтому второй абзац имеет слово **думаю**. Доказывать нечего, вот [статья](https://meduza.io/feature/2019/11/23/google-zapustila-strimingovyy-servis-stadia-s-nim-sovremennye-igry-rabotayut-dazhe-na-telefonah) с описанием проблем и чем недовольны пользователи.

Comment: Вывод статьи *"В целом журналисты и игроки сходятся в одном: Stadia и правда выглядит перспективно, это действительно технологии будущего. Но прямо сейчас все слишком сыро — да и доступ к сервису стоит слишком дорого."* отличается от вывода ответа *"Такие сервисы даже в ближайшем будущем не смогут существовать"*

Comment: @dIm0n Вот имеено, **выглядит** перспективно. Как сама идея не плохая.

Comment: Если не брать во внимание то, что будущее за 4к разрешением и 144Гц и выше, сейчас для минимальных требований комфортной игры нужно 1080P и 60fps. требуемая скорость передачи цифровых сигналов у HDMI и DP составляет намного выше, чем гигабитный интернет и это всё не считая задержки. Поэтму используя такие игровые сервисы мы получаем мыло и задержки. Когда интернет станет без задержек, тогда и поговорим. А крупные компании лишь патентуют всё на своём пути

Comment: Хорошо. А что если например склеить эти технологии. Например графику тупо минимально рисовать ,а все сложные вычисления делать на серверах ? Думаю это смодет разгрузить ПК юзера.